# how to induce semop call that fails with EINTR in linux?

Tags: c, semaphore

I m trying to induce EINTR failure with semop call.

```
key_t semkey;
int semid;
struct sembuf sbuf;
union semun {
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short *array;
} arg;
struct semid_ds ds;

/* Get unique key for semaphore. */
if ((semkey = ftok("/tmp", 'a')) == (key_t) -1) {
    perror("IPC error: ftok"); exit(1);
}
/* Get semaphore ID associated with this key. */
if ((semid = semget(semkey, 0, 0)) == -1) {
    /* Semaphore does not exist - Create. */
    if ((semid = semget(semkey, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR |
        S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH)) != -1)
    {
        /* Initialize the semaphore. */
        arg.val = 0;
        sbuf.sem_num = 0;
        sbuf.sem_op = 2;  /* This is the number of runs without queuing. */
        sbuf.sem_flg = 0;
        if (semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, arg) == -1
            || semop(semid, &sbuf, 1) == -1) {
            perror("IPC error: semop"); exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (errno == EEXIST) {
        if ((semid = semget(semkey, 0, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("IPC error 1: semget"); exit(1);
        }
        goto check_init;
    }
    else {
        perror("IPC error 2: semget"); exit(1);
    }
}
else
{
    /* Check that semid has completed initialization. */
    /* An application can use a retry loop at this point rather than
       exiting. */
    check_init:
    arg.buf = &ds;
    if (semctl(semid, 0, IPC_STAT, arg) < 0) {
        perror("IPC error 3: semctl"); exit(1);
    }
    if (ds.sem_otime == 0) {
        perror("IPC error 4: semctl"); exit(1);
    }
}

sbuf.sem_num = 0;
sbuf.sem_op = -1;
sbuf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
while (semop(semid, &sbuf, 1) == -1) 
{
    if (errno != EINTR)
    {
        perror("IPC Error: semop"); exit(1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Most i get is Resource unavailable failure or Resource busy. I even tried multiple semaphores running in two different threads or two different processes. but i dint able to get EINTR failure. i even tried sending signal as SIGCHLD to the process when sometime semop is waiting for the semaphores.

As per zwol suggestion,

Here is what i tried but it still dint work, i mean i can't get EINTR.

```
int g_global_variable = 0;
void *sigusr1_block_thread (void *vargp)
{
    while (1)
    {
        sleep (10);
        printf ("sigusr1_block_thread\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}
void *semop_wait_thread (void *vargp)
{
    int sem;
    struct sembuf sops[2];

    if((sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1,  IPC_CREAT | 0600))==-1){
        return NULL;
    }
    if(semctl(sem,0,SETVAL,2)==-1){
        exit(1);
    }

    sops[0].sem_num=0;     
    sops[0].sem_op=-1;     
    sops[0].sem_flg=0;      

    sops[1].sem_num=0;     
    sops[1].sem_op=0;     
    sops[1].sem_flg=0;

    g_global_variable = 1;
    printf ("Starting semop call \n");
    if(eintr_check_semop(sem, sops,2)<0)
        printf("Error semop\n");

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid, tid1, tid2, tid3, tid4;
    sigset_t set;
    int s;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, semop_wait_thread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, semop_wait_thread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, semop_wait_thread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid4, NULL, semop_wait_thread, NULL);


    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);

    s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        printf ("Error during pthread_sigmask");

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, sigusr1_block_thread, NULL);


    while (1)
    {
        sleep (1);
        if (g_global_variable == 1)
        {
            sleep (10);
            printf ("Send SIGUSR1/SIGCHLD signals \n");
            /* Send signal */
            pthread_kill( tid, SIGCHLD);
            pthread_kill( tid2, SIGCHLD);
            pthread_kill( tid3, SIGCHLD);
            pthread_kill( tid4, SIGCHLD);
            pthread_kill( tid1, SIGCHLD);
            pthread_kill( tid1, SIGUSR1);
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid3, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid4, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

eintr_check_semop just a function in which semop error and return values are checked. if EINTR it prints the message saying same.

if i send sigusr1 to blocking thread (t, t2, t3, t4) semop call break and comes of the loop.

I didnt get EINTR by any means. Then i checked kernel source code.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/ipc/sem.c

During EINTR, i see they are looping and not reporting the same.

Answer (score 0):

`EINTR` only happens when a process receives a signal while it's blocked on a blocking system call, and that signal has a handler, and that handler is configured to interrupt rather than restart system calls.  (There are a few exceptions to this principle, but none of them involve `semop`.)  Your program hasn't got any signal *handlers*, so EINTR won't happen, even if you do send it signals.

I can't tell you exactly how to do this off the top of my head, but the overall pattern that should work is:

1. Establish a signal handler for some signal. if you have no reason to pick some other specific signal, use `SIGUSR1` .  Use `sigaction` to do this, not `signal`, and do not include `SA_RESTART` in `sa_flags`.  The handler doesn't have to do anything; it just has to exist.
2. If the program has more than one thread, use `pthread_sigmask` to block `SIGUSR1` in every thread but one.
3. In the thread that has `SIGUSR1` unblocked, perform a `semop` operation that will block (a "wait-for-zero" on a semaphore with a nonzero value, without `IPC_NOWAIT`).
4. *After* the above thread is definitely blocked on `semop`, from another thread within the program, use `pthread_kill` to send `SIGUSR1` to the blocked thread.  Or, from outside the program, use regular `kill` to send `SIGUSR1` to the whole process; because the signal is unblocked in exactly one thread, that thread will receive the signal.

The hardest part is being sure that the thread is blocked on `semop` before the signal is sent.  I'm not sure this is possible from inside the program, without a race condition.

Comment: Thanks for the in sight; I will try them